# Google maps API not loading markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I went got a code snippet from the Google Maps API site, and was trying to modify it to implement in my code. I am using a text search (Google places) and then store each of the results in the "results" dictionary. I then implemented a loop to get the lat and long of each place to plot as markers on the map. I console log the creation of each marker, but for some reason the markers are not showing up. They are logging that each marker was created with its corresponding geographic location, just not showing up on the map. Here is my js code:

```js
// Initialize and add the map
let map;

async function initMap() {
  const position = { lat: 39.172192, lng: -86.519409 };
  // Request needed libraries.
  //@ts-ignore
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps", "places");
//   const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");

  // The map, centered at Uluru
  map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: position,
    mapId: "DEMO_MAP_ID",
  });

  // Create a PlacesService instance
  const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  // Perform a text search
  service.textSearch(
    {
      query: "recycling center",
      // You can add more parameters if needed
    },
    (results, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (const place of results) {
            // The markers
            const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: place.geometry.location,
                map: map,
                title: place.name,
            });
            marker.setVisible(true);

          console.log("Marker created: " + place.geometry.location)
          // Add a click event listener to the marker
        //   addMarkerClickListener(marker, place);
        }
      }
    }
  );
}

window.addEventListener('load', initMap);
```

And here is the page with my scripts loading the API:

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried to create a Google Map with markers for each location. The markers did not render.

Comment: 1) Looking at your code you've commented out the part that adds the marker to the map so that might be a problem. 2) Failing that - you haven't included `addMarkerClickListener` for us to to check if that's the problem.